# How to show a certain number of levels in django-mptt?

Tags: python, django, django-mptt

In my Django project I use [django-mptt](https://github.com/django-mptt/django-mptt) application to create hierarchical tree. Right now next code works well but I want to show only first  4 level of the tree. How to make it correctly? I am confused.

**views.py:**

```
context['caregories'] = Category.objects.get(id=5).get_descendants()
```

**html:**

```
{% load mptt_tags %}
<ul>
    {% recursetree caregories %}
        <li>
            {{ node.name }}
            {% if not node.is_leaf_node %}
                <ul class="children">
                    {{ children }}
                </ul>
            {% endif %}
        </li>
    {% endrecursetree %}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can filter the descendants by their level

```
obj = Category.objects.get(id=5)
context['caregories'] = obj.get_descendants().filter(level__lte=obj.level + max_depth)
```

where `max_depth` is the depth you require

Comment: Thank you for your help! =)